# Returning just the date portion of =NOW()-(WEEKDAY(NOW(),1)) in Excel 2007

Tags: excel-2007

I need to return just the date portion of the following formula: =NOW()-(WEEKDAY(NOW(),1)). Any ideas? I am using this formula to get the current date and then return the previous Saturday's date, but I am also getting the time component and I need to drop that portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I used: 
=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW()-(WEEKDAY(NOW(),1))))